# Error - value too large for column

Tags: sql, oracle, import, oracle-sqldeveloper

Yes, there are other instances of this question being asked, but I can't find an answer that is helpful.

I am using the data import wizard in oracle sql developer, the dataset to insert is about 8000 rows. I am consistently getting errors telling me the values I'm trying to insert are too large for the column.

I understand *exactly* what that means.

EDIT - ThatJeffSmith had a great answer below:

- Set preview limit to > row count
- Check for warning messages that alert me to possible width issues
- Adjust column width manually to a huge number (4000)

What happened is very odd, to me, please bear with me. I tried all those steps. I found that when I set the preview limit high, and I actually scrolled (with the mouse) all the way through, it adjusted some of the column widths in step 4, from say, 26, to 128. That was helpful, and meant I did not see #2, the column warning messages. Great. When I got to the final step, where I could look at the details, I opened the portion with the column headings and their definitions, and the column widths were STILL UNCHANGED from what they were before!

I ran into this over and over again, until I clicked on *each* column name in step 4 (image 2 below), such that all column names were bolded. All the column widths were correct, they still showed the original, incorrect lengths in the final window, but after clicking on all of them...it actually imported correctly and completely.

OK, so I got it.

Can someone tell me what is going on, IE why I had to go through that many steps?

I am very confused. I am not a programmer persay, but have used things like SPSS, R, STATA, SAS, etc in the past...it is never an issue with any of those...they read through the data, and set the width appropriately.

At any rate, thank you JeffSmith for providing a great in-depth answer, you are truly The Man. If anyone has insight into why it only worked after I clicked on each column, please let me know, it's very confusing, and I'd love to not have to do that again.

[image: visual help]

Comment: If this is specifically about SQL Developer it would be worth tagging it.

Comment: Good call, tag added.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely!

[image]

Set the preview limit appropriately.

Note, the higher you set it, the more memory you're asking to use so we can read in ALL the data.

Then, when you get to the column definition:

[image]

If you set the new column too narrow, based on what we KNOW by the preview window of rows we've read into memory, we'll show you there's a problem in the Data Preview panel. 8000 rows might take awhile to scroll, but you'll know there's an issue there based on the Source Data Columns warning indicator.

Then, we offer 3 suggestions for you via the drop-down:

First number - big enough to fit the max size and then some
Second number - round up to a 'medium' level max size
Third number - round up to a theoretical max size based on your data sample.

All of these are educated best guesses. You should have a data model to consult ;)

Comment: Please see my heavily edited original question. You were *very* helpful, but I still had a lot of issues getting it to work. Any insight you could provide would be very appreciated.

Comment: Need more info @Adam_S - were there only 8000 records to import? and you set the import preview to 8000, and you adjust the new column width as indicated, and still found records too wide to fit? if so, that would be a bug. you can email me your csv/excel to jeff.d.smith@oracle.com. this can be an iterative process FWIW, it takes me 2 or 3 times to get everything just 'right'. creating a new oracle table isn't a trivial task - you generally have to live with these decisions for a LONG time. so size and define the columns as appropriate for the data going fwd, not juts what's in your one xlsx

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem before.  It involved frequent captures of excel data.  The data was always in the same format, so I wrote a macro to assess the character length of each cell and sum across the row.  It would then sort the table highest to lowest by the combined character length of the row.  This always managed to place the longest character lengths of each column into the top 50 so that the default format would always be determined as the most generous for the column.  I guess this might help if you are also performing excel captures, though that is not obvious from your question.